# How to distribute Python libraries to users without internet

Tags: python, anaconda, software-distribution

Package managers like conda, pip and their online repositories make distributing packages easy and robust. But I am looking for ways to distribute to users that want to install and run my library on machines that are deliberately disconnected from internet for security purposes.

I am to assume these computers don't have Python or any other packages or package managers like conda installed. I am also looking for recommended workflows for bundling my dependencies with the package as well.

Comment: How is user supposed to run your library without having python installed? If you meant "offline" installation of your package . you can install pip offline and then distribute  offline package.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

1. Create a pip repository in the offline network.
2. Deploy your project with its dependencies. Use setuptools to create a `setup.py` file for easy installation.
3. Use py2exe to create an executable instead of a python program.

Comment: This works if I have access to the end user's network but I don't. While standing up an offline pip network is scalable, this might be a stretch to expect from my users unfortunately.

Comment: What can you access?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with option 2 (provide a python installation as well) and with option 3?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps:

1. Create a virtual environment for the project. This link will help you create virtual environments http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
2. Add all the libraries that you want to use to this environment on your system.
3. Then zip the virtual environment folder and send it over. They can just use    the virtual environment that you sent.

Comment: Virtual environments aren't necessarily portable.